# Typesafe callback system in modern C++

Tags: c++, templates, boost, callback

I'm working at a module that use a callback system that wasn't implemented very nice. The clients are registering with an ID and will be called back with a variable (or two, or none). The problem is that for almost every ID is a different variable. (Ex: Id1 -> `char*`, Id2 -> `int`). This is achieved by passing variable via a pointer. So callback looks like

```
typedef void (*NotifFunctionPtr)(void* ctx, const void* option);
```

There are many problems with this approach like, and I want to replace this with a (type) safe and modern way of handling this. However this isn't as simple as it looks like, I have some ideas (`like boost::function` or replacing the `void*` with a struct that encapsulate type and ptr) but i think maybe there is a better idea, so I was wondering **what is the modern way of settings a typesafe callback in C++**.

Edit: Another idea is registering an callback with a type T via a template function that  calls back with the same type T. Is this viable or implemented in a library somewere ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is not that of callbacks, but rather that you want to treat all callbacks as the same type, when they are not (the signatures are different). So either you do the nasty C `void*` trick or if you want to use a *type-safe* approach you will have to pay for it, and provide different methods to register the different callback types --which IMHO is the right way.

Once you have solved that, you can use the `signals` or `signals2` libraries or else implement your own wheel using `function` as a base (to avoid having to rewrite the type erasure).

Comment: There is also an option of replacing void pointers with `boost::any`. I'd certainly suggest separate signals (using boost or sigc++) over anything using IDs, but if that much refactoring is not viable, `boost::any` would allow at least runtime checking that you are getting correct types.

Comment: @JanHudec: Yes, that's true, `boost::any` will provide a *type-safe* solution *at runtime*, that is, it will not fail to compile, but fail to execute if you pass the wrong type of arguments. Still much better than the `void*` and/or unions that would silently cause UB if you failed to match the types.

Comment: what about a template function that register a callback with a type `T` and calls back with the same type `T`.

Comment: @cprogrammer: I was thinking in callbacks that outlive a single function call, in which case the problem with your proposal is how to store them (requires type erasure) and at the same time be able to safely *know* what arguments to pass later on in a type-safe manner.

Comment: yes, this is not type-safe as I required, but the garbage will be inside the callback class. Not necessary a good idea.

Comment: @cprogrammer: Templates won't help (much). The code that calls the callback provides specific type. You either need to know that type when registering (the singals option; you can use templates to allow assigning function taking different but compatible types) or you check it at runtime (boost::any).

Answer (score 3):

`boost::function` is just the right choice here. You gain the type-safety of function objects without having to change the code much.

Answer (score 2):

If you already looked into boost. Why not use the [signals](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/signals.html) or [signals2](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/signals2.html) library.

Comment: I don't know if resolves the problem with different number arguments.